# How to run bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto through REST API?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, kibana

I need to direct update the password at the initial phase and not want to go through generating random password to provide access to user through rest API. please help

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to set [`bootstrap.password`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#bootstrap-elastic-passwords) in the [Keystore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/elasticsearch-keystore.html) before starting Elasticsearch. (If you`re using docker, there is an [env variable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-configuration-methods) for this purpose too.)

Afterward, you can use the `elastic` user and the previously set [`bootstrap.password`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#bootstrap-elastic-passwords) in order to [update the build-in user's password](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/security-api-change-password.html) via the [REST-Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/security-api-change-password.html). This approach is also described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html#set-built-in-user-passwords).

Consider also changing the password for the build-in elastic user.